# iOS In-App Purchases getting stuck in 'Purchasing' state

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

I'm getting a weird error with in-app purchases for a project.

The client’s reporting that when they purchase an auto-renewing subscription, nothing happens; logging indicates that the app is correctly adding the payment to the queue, but it never gets any state change notifications on that transaction (i.e. it stays in the Purchasing state forever).

When the app launches, it registers as a listener to the payment queue (as per Apple's guidelines), and it sees the transactions from earlier still there, and still in the Purchasing state. For example, in one log that I've received, it's found that there are six transactions in the queue, and all of them are in the Purchasing state.

What I suspect is happening is that a payment has gotten stuck somehow in the Purchasing state, and has never transitioned to Purchased or Failed. As a result, other transactions are piling up behind it. However, my searching hasn't found any other reports of this kind.

The end result here is that there's never any UI that appears when the user, on *some* (but not all) of their devices, begins an in-app purchase.

My background reading suggests that it's potentially related to the following questions:

- [Multitasking and SKPaymentQueue I get a "stuck" SKPaymentTransaction with a transactionState of SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685680/multitasking-and-skpaymentqueue-i-get-a-stuck-skpaymenttransaction-with-a-tran)
- [SKPaymentTransactionObserver not getting a callback on app switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938048/skpaymenttransactionobserver-not-getting-a-callback-on-app-switch)

However, when I attempted to reproduce their behaviour (of switching away from the app in the middle of a transaction) by pressing the Home button to switch away, the button press was ignored by the system; I tried to force the issue by killing the app from Xcode, but that actually just kept the UI on screen while the app was removed.

This issue isn’t being reported by all testers, and I’m not able to reproduce it myself, but the log is very clear about what the purchases are doing on the devices encountering this problem. My question: **under what circumstances could a purchase be ‘stuck’ like this?**

For context, this is all on the sandbox environment, and on iOS 11.2+.

Comment: Are you checking that it's not actually stuck in the [deferred state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate/skpaymenttransactionstatedeferred?language=objc)?

Comment: Yes, I am - the purchases are definitely in the Purchasing state, and not Deferred. I had thought that this might be a case of the user not realising they had Ask To Buy set up, but if that were the case, transactions would be deferred; additionally, transactions that are Deferred and not approved within 24 hours should transition to Failed, and that's not what I'm seeing either.

Comment: Any chance this is a new thing? Super weird, after reading this I had a user report the same thing. Idk if it's a coincidence but I'll post back if I figure anything out.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: The resolution for me was restarting the phone!

Comment: I'm also having this issue but in my case, it is happening on macOS 10.15.1. I am also looking for a reason. I've checked state, it remains in the purchasing state. And then no notification or call back.